# Unix shell script not executing from another script

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have written the below command using a shell script:

```
/usr/bin/find ${FilePath[$i]} -name ${FileName[$i]}* -type f -mtime +${DaysNo[$i]} | grep ${FilePath[$i]}$tempfile > tempFilesList
```

It looks good when I execute this script directly, but gives me below error when I try to execute it from *another* shell script.

```
ERROR : /usr/bin/find: bad option resultmgr.log_2019-11-07
/usr/bin/find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that `${FileName[$i]}*` is being expanded to *multiple* file names which would give you something like `-name file1 file2` in your command.

That could happen if, for example, files matching that mask existed in your current working directory for the case where you run it from another script, but *not* when you're running it from the command line. Some shells will expand if possible but leave alone if not, as per the following transcript:

```
~> echo testprog*
testprog testprog.c
~> echo nosuchfile*
nosuchfile*
~> _
```

That `file2` would then be considered a control argument to `find` and therefore invalid.

You can check this by simply echoing out the command before running it:

```
echo Will run: /usr/bin/find ${FilePath[$i]} -name ${FileName[$i]}* -type f -mtime +${DaysNo[$i]} ...
```

and seeing what it outputs.

Comment: i echo the find command it gave me below output.
/usr/bin/find /var/opt/app/incontrol/Logs/IPC/ -name agent.log* -type f -mtime +10 | grep /var/opt/app/incontrol/Logs/IPC/agent.log

it gave me same output when i ran this directly in a script or calling this script from another script.